# binding xml using C# in WPF

Tags: c#

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Categories>
<Product>
<Product_id>dave</Product_id>
<Product_name>smith</Product_name>
<Product_price>none</Product_price>
</Product>
</Categories>
```

I want to bind this via code, as I have really struggled with WPF and XAML. Unless anybody can show me an easy way.

The following C#

```
XmlDataProvider xds= new XmlDataProvider();
        xds.Source = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Roi\Desktop\dave\Sum.xml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        xds.XPath = "/Categories/Product/@Product_id";
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = xds;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(listView1, ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

Any help would be greatful.

Thank you

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somthing like this should work :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400" Name="UI" >

    <Grid>
        <ListView DataContext="{Binding MyXmlDataSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/Product/@Product_id}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You will want to add a `DependencyProperty` on you Window/Control for the XmlDataProvider

```
public XmlDataProvider MyXmlDataSource
{
    get { return (XmlDataProvider)GetValue(MyXmlDataSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyXmlDataSourceProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyXmlDataSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyXmlDataSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyXmlDataSource", typeof(XmlDataProvider), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

then you can assign your XmlDataProvider

```
XmlDataProvider xds= new XmlDataProvider();
        xds.Source = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Roi\Desktop\dave\Sum.xml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        xds.XPath = "/Categories";

MyXmlDataSource = xds;
```

Comment: Hi Sa_ddam. I should have made myself clear. The reason to why I have this coded in C# is because I plan to have a changing XmlDataProvider and I don't know how to do this in XAML

Comment: What do you mean by "a changing XmlDataProvider"?  It sounds like you should be exposing your data as a property (either a DependencyProperty or with INotifyPropertyChanged) from your C#, and _that's_ what you'd bind your WPF/XAML to.